# shape mismatch while copy weights from own trained net in caffe

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I get shape mismatch error on FC-layer when I try to load trained net in C++.
My input layer in TRAIN/TEST phase (differ only by source and batch size, some params are omitted):

```
layer {
    type: "ImageData"
    image_data_param {
        batch_size: 8
        new_height: 256
        new_width: 256
    }
    transform_param {
        crop_size: 227
    }
}
```

Input layer for deploy:

```
layer {
    type: "Input"
    input_param { shape: { dim: 1 dim: 3 dim: 256 dim: 256 }}
}
```

Error:

> Cannot copy param 0 weights from layer 'fc4'; shape mismatch. Source param shape is 8 26912 (215296); target param shape is 8 32768 (262144).

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36509155/4996059) answer, but my own model is trained and tested.
Could you shed some light on this?

Comment: I would expect the mismatch to appear much earlier than **fc4**.  Can you post your topology?

Comment: @Prune if all layers preceding `fc4` are `"Convolution"` layers, than there is no issue only for the fully-connected layer.

Comment: @Shai -- correct.  That's why I'm trying to gather more information.  The inputs, so far as reported, are the same size.  A series of CONV layers would produce no error.  However, mismatched input could/should trip up the first CONV.

Comment: @Prune the inputs are not the same size: there is cropping during training that is missing from the deploy. see my answer for more details

Comment: RIght, but .. oh ... got it now.  I mentally slipped a matching crop into the deploy.  Duh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are feeding your nets with different sized inputs: during training you are **cropping** the inputs to 227x277, while during test you do not crop and leave the images at 256x256. This results with the error you got.

Comment: thanks, I don't understand `crop_size` param of input layers. [Official tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/data.html) says: **random cropping can be done as simple data augmentation**. And I thought it's something like random crop & scale with peserving main size (256).

Comment: 1) Why then need the `new_height` and `new_width` parameters?

Comment: 2) If I change my `input_param shape` to 227 during test, I get **Network should have exactly one input** error. Is it because of new input size of the model?

Comment: @esterlein don't you miss label input?

Comment: The 1st question is clear now. @Shai no, full deploy input defined as `input_param { shape: { dim: 1 dim: 3 dim: 227 dim: 227 } shape: { dim: 1 dim: 1 }}` with two top blobs. Train/test input was defined as `image_data_param { source: "/home/....txt" }` with two tops.

Comment: @esterlein regarding the new error - I suppose you need to ask a new question with more details regarding the error message.